# QFile read timeout

Tags: c++, qt, nfs

My application needs to read files from a `nfs` mount point. I'm using `QFile::read(BUFFER_SIZE);` which works as it is supposed to. The problem is, when the `nfs` unmounts (patchy network issues), this `QFile::read()` never timesout resulting in application hang. Any sensible solutions please?

Thanks.

Comment: "patchy network issues" - Can you check for a network error?

Comment: Does `QFile::readData ( char * data, qint64 maxSize )` have the same behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to how NFS works. The process is stuck in the OS system call, in uninterruptible sleep. So, I think you have two reliable options:

- Move file reading to another *thread*. It and its event loop may get stuck, just code your main thread so that it won't matter for the whole application. There are a few ways to go about using threads for this, but if you are not reading arbitrary number of different files at the same time, it'd probably be best to launch a dedicated thread for reading the single file, and then let the thread finish once everything is read. For this, you might even just subclass `QThread`, and override `run()` method with your own reading loop (you can still emit signals for progress if you want, you just can't receive them queued without Qt's event loop).
- Move file reading to another *process*. In other words, write a small tool program or script which does the actual reading, and sends the contents to your main process. That way you should be able to kill the reading process without killing the whole application, should that become necessary. Again you have to decide if you want a separate single-use process for each reading (so you can give file name as command line paramater, for example), or if you launch one child process and implement communication with it so you can request files (or parts of files). Qt's `QProcess` makes this approach easy, too.

Comment: Thanks for your time. We (software team) had a little chat and came up with the second solution as well. Back to my desk, your answer was here. Amazing. Accepting this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QFile::bytesAvailable ()` inherited from `QIODevice` which returns the number of bytes that are available for reading. Wait in a while loop until the bytes are available or some seconds elapsed :

```
QFile file("file.dat");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QElapsedTimer timer;
timer.start();

while(file.bytesAvailable()<BUFFER_SIZE || timer.nsecsElapsed()<3e9)
    qApp->processEvents();

QByteArray array
if(file.waitForReadyRead())
{
   array = file.read(BUFFER_SIZE);
}
```

Here it will wait 3 seconds for the data to be ready. The elapsed time is measured by `QElapsedTimer`. If `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes are not available after the timeout then it will continue with out hanging.

Comment: Which version of `Qt` does support this? I can't find `waitForReadyRead()` in Qt 4.8 documentation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The actual problem is `file.read()` function. Even after making sure `bytesAvaiable()` and `waitForReadyRead()` are `true`, if network goes away whilst in `read()`, application still hangs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QIODevice::readChannelFinished()` signal and connect it to a slot that close the file reader

Comment: Event loop is struck until `read()` returns, so will this signal work?